# OpenWRT configuration with the Vodafone Station Revolution

Tags: static, lan, openwrt, dhcp

I have a Vodafone Station Revolution (HW huawei) connected in the same LAN with a switch/router (OpenWRT).....

My PC is connected to the switch/router (OpenWRT) and it seems that after 2 minutes that I surf on internet with my PC, the connection with  192.168.1.1 (the gateway of Vodafone station Revolution) is dropped and, analyzing the network traffic with tcpdump, it seems that an ARP request ("Who is the 192.168.1.1") has been recursively sent by OpenWRT.

My question is:

It is possible to perform a more detailed troubleshooting on the network?
Has the vodafone Station Revolution some specifics that usually blocks the normal switch functions (on others Switch/router connected on the same lan)?

Below my current lan's configuration:

{internet} <---> (vodafone_station[192.168.1.1] <---> cable ethernet <---> openWRT (192.168.1.200)<---> myPC (DHCP of Vodefaone_station) )

Comment: you should ask this kind of questions on superuser or serverfault

Comment: If arp is too frequent, then its possible that Vodafone_station is banning the traffic from that port. Check for any kinds of physical loops!!!

Comment: It seems that the problem has been solved: there were 2 DHCP server running on the same net, and each static IP should be declarate on the VSR;